# Matplotlib + d3 + mpld3: Interactively shrink or stretch axes

Tags: python, d3.js, matplotlib, web, mpld3

I am using matplotlib in order to create a plot like this:

`plot = plt.plot(data[[x]], data[[y]], 'o-')`

Then, I create a interactive [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) plot using [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/)

`visualization_html = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)`

Result: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYQrV.png)

Sometimes, plots are not very well readable, because the axes would need a individual and flexible streching or shrinking. There is the possibility of zooming or moving the canvas - but how could I realise streching and shrinking by user input (i.e. mouse gesture)?

Comment: I guess this is a bit too broad. I would guess you need to write the JavaScript to do that yourself.

Comment: That being said, I think I had to re-render the whole matplotlib plot, which seems very inefficient.